# Get file path from IHyperlink

Tags: eclipse, hyperlink, eclipse-plugin, console

Assuming I have an `IHyperlink` object, which I get from my Console (actually it is `JavaStackTraceHyperlink`).
Is there an option to get the file path it uses?

Answer (score 2):

No there is no official API to get the file path.

`JavaStackTraceHyperlink` does not have the file path and ends up searching the workspace when it needs to find the class.

Both `JavaStackTraceHyperlink` and the search methods it uses are **internal** classes and are therefore not part of the API.

Comment: So, if I'm building a plugin and want to get the stack trace of a single run and put markers on the lines of the stack trace, in the right project, is there a good way to do it? This is my first plugin so I don't have much of ideas...

Comment: I guess you would have to use something like the `org.eclipse.ui.console.consolePatternMatchListeners` extension point to pick up the stack trace and something like the Eclipse JDT Search Engine to find the matching class.